# Как сгенерировать stream дат?

Tags: java, java-stream

Нужно сгенерировать `Stream<LocalDate>` начиная с 01.01.1970

```
public void test {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.ofEpochDay(365);
    System.out.println("day of:" + ld);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Java 9** и более поздние

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1);
Stream<LocalDate> dates = start.datesUntil(LocalDate.now());
```

**Java 8**

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1970, Month.JANUARY, 1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();

Stream<LocalDate> dates = Stream.iterate(start, d -> d.plusDays(1))
                                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end));
```

Comment: выводит ошибку в "datesUntil".

Comment: @AndrewKorpach версия Java какая?

Comment: NetBeans IDE 8.2

Comment: @AndrewKorpach версия Java, а не IDE. Есть разница между языком и средой разработки.

Comment: прошу прощение, у меня 8 версия Java. Благодарю за объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант на Java 8 и выше:

```
Stream<LocalDate> dates = LongStream
    .rangeClosed(0, LocalDate.now().toEpochDay())
    .mapToObj(LocalDate::ofEpochDay);
```

В отличие от варианта из соседнего ответа такой стрим будет иметь характеристику `SIZED`.